# Old ids in R.java file

Tags: android

Even though I have deleted some strings from my strings.xml file they still show up in the generated R.java file, cleaning also doesn't help.

Furthermore there are some weird parts of my own comments inside the R file, has anyone encountered this?

Part of the generated R.java file:

```
  public static final int description_subtitleImage=0x7f050020;
    public static final int hello=0x7f050000;
    /**  Config 
 Config 
     */
    public static final int host=0x7f05000f;
    public static final int launcher_app_name=0x7f05001a;
    public static final int msg_close=0x7f050005;
    /**  Message texts 
 Message texts 
     */
    public static final int msg_error=0x7f050003;
    public static final int msg_error_close=0x7f05000e;
```

Thats a small part of my strings.xml file (with the comment showing up in the R.java file)

```
<!-- Config -->
<string name="host">Host:</string>
<string name="port">Port:</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that comments in xml files of the form:

```
<!-- Might end up as a javadoc in R.java -->
```

end up being converted into Javadoc type comments in the generated R.java as:

```
/**  Might end up as a javadoc in R.java 
*/
```

I suppose this is vaguely useful.

Answer (score 1):

In res->values->strings.xml use remove.
Then clean and rebuild your project.
Your olds ids will be disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the gen folder, it should automagically regenerate the folder and files. If not then do a clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the R.java file (it won't be a problem as it is self generated file). It might work.